# How to fix breaking images via CORS error (or csp) in Nuxt?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I'm trying to render some images from a uri in nuxt(getting images from auth0), but i keep getting this error:

> Refused to load the image because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "img-src 'self' data:".

how does one go about fixing this?

Comment: Why are you mentioning CORS? The error message says "Content Security Policy". It doesn't mention CORS at all.

Comment: "how does one go about fixing this?" — You change your CSP. Have you looked up CSPs on MDN (or using Google) so you understand how they work? Have you located your current CSP which is blocking the request so you can change it?